# No Working C Compiler Found

Tags: c++, ios, c, gcc, ffmpeg

I just downloaded it from here to try it:

http://www.videolan.org/developers/x264.html

I ran ./configure. It complained that I didn't have an assembler and suggested I ran ./configure --disable-asm. Then all seemed to compile OK.

How did you install gcc? From the repositories?

After i check the GCC version by using (gcc --version) command in terminal. The log is

```
i686-apple-darwin11-llvm-gcc-4.2
(GCC) 4.2.1 (Based on Apple Inc. build 5658)
(LLVM build 2336.11.00)
```

how can i solve this issue ..? I want to make compile and install.

Comment: Did you install command line tools?

Comment: Did you solved that problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check config.log and search for "working C compiler". You will see the error that caused the test to fail.

You really need to supply more information (for example, the output of running configure). "Then all seemed to compile OK." is especially confusing. If "all seemed to compile OK", what is your problem?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that you don't have required yasm,
go through below link & download.

http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/yasm.html

Steps to follow :

1. download from above link
2. extract files
3. ./configure
4. make
5. make install #
6. yasm --version
    if it is 1.3.0 then its OK, otherwise reply me if you are not getting right version details
7. again try to install your software, you will definitely find right assembler